# ValueError: seek of closed file Working on PyPDF2 and getting this error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pypdf

I am trying to get text out of a pdf file. Below is the code:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader
with open('HTTP_Book.pdf', 'rb') as file:
    pdf = PdfFileReader(file)

page = pdf.getPage(1)
#print(dir(page))
print(page.extractText())
```

This gives me the error

```
ValueError: seek of closed file
```

I just put the code under the `with` statement, and it works fine. My question is: why is this so? I have already stored the information in 'pdf' object so i should be able to access it outside the  block.

Comment: Please show a traceback and the actual code that shows the second error

Comment: added above as per suggestion

Comment: Thanks. Looks like your pdf package doesn't support Python 3

Comment: But i just ran same code by changing pdf file. It gives some results with error: ```PdfReadWarning: Xref table not zero-indexed. ID numbers for objects will be corrected. [pdf.py:1736]```

Comment: That's a reasonable warning. The error in the question looks like what you get when you expect a python 2 bytes, which is str, but run in python 3, where bytes are integers. Not sure how you got that.

Comment: Are you running in different virtual environments? Have different versions of Python or PyPDF installed? What versions do you have?

Comment: only single version of each ```$ py --version
Python 3.7.2 
``` and ```$ pip freeze | grep PyPDF2
PyPDF2==1.26.0
```

Comment: Can you attach a sample of the pdf or a link to it here please?

Comment: i tried with another pdf and results are as expected so i guess i should change the module/ method. Can't rely on it. https://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/1.1/rfc2616.pdf this is the link btw

Comment: and if you can help with my first question please?

Comment: Could you split your question into two please? I would be happy to post an answer to part 1 here, but could you make part 2, with the link above into a separate question?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Done.

Comment: Where is part 2? I'll take a look at it later today if I get a chance.

Comment: @MadPhysicist here's part2 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55993860/getting-typeerror-ord-expected-string-of-length-1-but-int-found-error

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[`PdfFileReader`](https://pythonhosted.org/PyPDF2/PdfFileReader.html#PyPDF2.PdfFileReader) expects a seekable, open, steam. It does not load the entire file into memory, so you have to keep it open to run the methods, like [`getPage`](https://pythonhosted.org/PyPDF2/PdfFileReader.html#PyPDF2.PdfFileReader.getPage). Your hypothesis that creating a reader automatically reads in the whole file is incorrect.

A [`with`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) statement operates on a [context manager](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers), such as a file. When the `with` ends, the context manager's `__exit__` method is called. In this case, it closes the file handle that your `PdfFildReader` is trying to use to get the second page.

As you found out, the correct procedure is to read what you must from the PDF before you close the file. If, and only if, your program needs the PDF open until the very end, you can pass the file name directly to `PdfFileReader`. There is no (documented) way to close the file after that though, so I would recommend your original approach:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader
with open('HTTP_Book.pdf', 'rb') as file:
    pdf = PdfFileReader(file)
    page = pdf.getPage(1)
    print(page.extractText())
# file is closed here, pdf will no longer do its job
```

Comment: I think you are right. PdfFileReader doesn't store anything. It needs an open file till its task is complete. Although we can extract data and use it later. That is stored in the memory.                                                                     .```with open('test_2.pdf','rb') as file:
    pdf=PdfFileReader(file)
    page=pdf.getPage(2)
    data=page.extractText()
print(data[:40])```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, try to indent the last lines into the with section.
Work for me after 2 days of searching.

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader
with open('HTTP_Book.pdf', 'rb') as file:
    pdf = PdfFileReader(file)

    page = pdf.getPage(1)
    #print(dir(page))
    print(page.extractText())
```

Comment: Technically correct, but what does this add beyond the accepted answer?